# UIWebView ignoring disk cache?

Tags: ios, caching, ios8, uiwebview, persistent-storage

In my hybrid app I name web resource for instance `main.css?{timestamp-file-was-modified}` and give them a year-long max-age cache header so that the clients should keep it more or less forever.

What seems to happen in my iOS app is, however, that the `UIWebView` honors the cache header during the app's lifetime, i.e. when I load a new page that also includes `main.css?{same-timestamp}` it won't even try to revalidate as it knows it has the right file in cache. **BUT**, upon a fresh launch of the app (after being killed or device switched off) the `UIWebView` fetches all resources again, ignoring the cache. I've run it through Charles Proxy to verify this is the case.

I've looked inside the SQlite cache.db and I see that `main.css?{same-timestamp}` is there, but still the `UIWebView` won't load it from cache, causing the initial page load to be significantly slower than it could be.

I've tried it on an iPhone with iOS 8.4 and an iPad with iOS 8.2. Same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you really like to control cache, you can register your custom NSURLProtocol subclass in delegate and then using `- (void)startLoading` you can load anything from local storage.